# PhantomJS page fetching with nested loop to get new pages

Tags: javascript, url, phantomjs

I want to fetch a list online from a certain URL that is in JSON format and then use the DATA_ID from each item in that list to call a new URL. I'm just new with PhantomJS and I can't figure out why nest loops inside the page.open() acts all weird. Also the way to use phantom.exit() seems to be really weird doing what I want to achieve.

Here's my code:

```
console.log('Loading recipes');
console.log('===============================================================');

var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.hiddenurl.com/recipes/all';

page.open(url, function (status) {
    //Page is loaded!
    var js = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0];
    });

    var recipes = JSON.parse(js.innerHTML).results;
    //console.log(recipes[0].name.replace('[s]', ''));

    for (i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++) {
        console.log(recipes[i].name.replace('[s]', ''));

        var craft_page = require('webpage').create();
        var craft_url = 'http://www.hiddenurl.com/recipe/' + recipes[i].data_id;

        craft_page.open(craft_url, function (craft_status) {
            //Page is loaded!
            var craft_js = craft_page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            });

            var craftp = craft_js.innerHTML;
            console.log('test');
        });

        if (i == 5) {
            console.log('===============================================================');
            phantom.exit();
            //break;
        }
    }
});
```

The thing that happens here is that this line:

```
console.log(recipes[i].name.replace('[s]', ''));
```

..prints the following:

```
===============================================================
Item from DATA_ID 1
Item from DATA_ID 2
Item from DATA_ID 3
Item from DATA_ID 4
Item from DATA_ID 5
```

..then it just prints the next:

```
===============================================================
```

..followed by:

```
'test'
'test'
'test'
'test'
'test'
```

Why is this not happening serial? The data from the innerly called page() request gets heaped up and dumped at the end, even after phantom.exit() should actually already be called.

Also when I free-loop a normal data-set I get this error:

```
QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate(): Unable to create thread pipe: Too many open files
2013-01-31T15:35:18 [FATAL] QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate(): Can not continue without a thread pipe
Abort trap: 6
```

Is there any way I can set GLOBAL_PARAMETERS or direct the process in some way so I can just handle 100's of page requests?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a workaround with Python by calling PhantomJS separately through the shell, like this:

```
import os
import json

cmd = "./phantomjs fetch.js"
fin,fout = os.popen4(cmd)
result = fout.read()

recipes = json.loads(result)

print recipes['count']
```

Not the actual solution for the PhantomJS issue, but it's a working solution and has less problems with memory and code-structure.